Mediation agreed on settement
i agreed to pay a settlement to the attorney in two installments. i paid the first half 2 months ago now its time to pay the 2nd half. I don't have the money and the person that sued me is back in jail. His attorney is handling  his case. So, whats happens if I don't pay because I don't have the money now.

That the person entitled to the money is in jail is not relevant. People in jail still have rights, and their properties are not forfeit because they are in jail. If you owed him before he went to jail and did not pay, you still owe him.

The answer depends on how the settlement was structured, which we don't know. Possible outcomes include contempt of court, a reopening of the lawsuit, a whole new lawsuit, and nothing.

This answer could be improved by providing a citation for reference.

People being in jail doesn't absolve their debtors of responsibility for paying the debts.
Further, the attorney still represents the person no matter where they are in the world, which is a key feature of having an attorney.
What happens if you don't pay an agreed-upon sum is dependent on the contract.  Generally, the other party would take the non-paying party to court to obtain a judgement, which can be enforced by numerous methods including the sheriff shows up and starts auctioning off the non-paying party's assets.  Another typical method is garnishment of wages.
